# More efficient way to filter my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the data frame below and I basically need to find all groups without A or A,U and save it to Excel

| Name | Group1 | Group2 | Group3 | Group4 | Group5 | Group6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AppUser |  |  |  | A |  |  |
| ShareUser | A |  | A |  | A,U |  |
| MediaUser |  |  |  | A |  |  |
| WebUser |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| PrintUser | A,U |  | A |  | A,U |  |

Currently this is what I have and its working fine but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way the Pro's would do it?

My current working code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

#Source file
File = Path.cwd() /"./UserGrid.xlsx"

#Read excel file
df = pd.read_excel(File)

#Replace A,U with A
df2 = df.replace(('A,U'), 'A')

#Change Index
df3 = df2.set_index('Name')

#Remove all groups that has an admin
df4=df3.columns[df3.ne('A').all()].tolist()
df5=pd.DataFrame(df4, columns =['No Admins'])

#Save to Excel
dfexcel = pd.DataFrame(df5)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('./No_Admins.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
dfexcel.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='NoAdmins', index=False)
col_idx = dfexcel.columns.get_loc('No Admins')
writer.sheets['NoAdmins'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, 50)
writer.close()
```

I had trouble filtering out A and A,U so I ended up replacing all the A,U with A in the data frame. Just checking if there is a more efficient way or should I leave it like this.

Comment: What does your expected output look like? A data frame with only columns `"Group1"` and `"Group6"`?

Comment: `"Group2"`** and `"Group6"`

Comment: The expected output is a df with just columns in 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

You could use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to impute the missing values with an empty string, apply a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) over the `"A"` and `"A,U"` values, [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) columns that are all null, get the [`columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html), then convert [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_frame.html).

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer=StringIO(
        """Name Group1  Group2  Group3  Group4  Group5  Group6
AppUser             A       
ShareUser   A       A       A,U 
MediaUser               A       
WebUser                     
PrintUser   A,U     A       A,U """
    ),
    sep="\t",
    index_col="Name"
)

out = (
    df.fillna("")
    .mask(df.isin(["A", "A,U"]))
    .dropna(axis="columns")
    .columns
    .to_frame(name="No Admins")
)

print(out)
```

```
       No Admins
Group2    Group2
Group6    Group6
```

## Option 2

Use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to check which cells have either `"A"` or `"A,U"`, flip the values to `False` using [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), check which columns are [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) `True`, filter out the `False`s, grab the [`index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) and convert [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_frame.html)

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer=StringIO(
        """Name Group1  Group2  Group3  Group4  Group5  Group6
AppUser             A       
ShareUser   A       A       A,U 
MediaUser               A       
WebUser                     
PrintUser   A,U     A       A,U """
    ),
    sep="\t",
    index_col="Name"
)

out = (
    df.isin(["A", "A,U"])
    .eq(False)
    .all()
    .loc[lambda x: x]
    .index.to_frame(name="No Admins")
)

print(out)
```

```
       No Admins
Group2    Group2
Group6    Group6
```

## NOTE: exporting `out` to excel and ignoring the index will result in a frame that looks like this:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter("out.xlsx") as writer:
    out.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

[image: xlsx]

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for the solution!  Will be using option 2

Answer (score 0):

How about using np.select?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'Group1': [np.nan, 'A', np.nan, np.nan, 'A, U'], 'Group2': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'Group3': [np.nan, 'A', np.nan, np.nan, 'A'], 'Group4': [np.nan, 'A', np.nan, 'A', np.nan],
                   'Group5': [np.nan, 'A, U', np.nan, np.nan, 'A, U']})



condition = [(df['Group1'] == 'A, U') | (df['Group1'] == 'A') | (df['Group2'] == 'A, U') | (df['Group2'] == 'A') |
             (df['Group3'] == 'A, U') | (df['Group3'] == 'A')
             | (df['Group4'] == 'A, U') | (df['Group4'] == 'A') | (df['Group5'] == 'A, U') | (df['Group5'] == 'A')]

choices = [True]

df['is_AU'] = np.select(condition, choices)
df = df.loc[df['is_AU'] == 0]
df = df.drop(columns='is_AU')
```